# Attribute to select Route/Action based on presence of Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I thought, but I'm not sure, that there were built-in Attributes we could decorate our Actions with, which would select/skip the Actions based on the presence of a Parameter or Model Bind Variable.

I was thinking something like this:

```
/*   [Route("/Objectives"), MandatoryParam("CourseId")]
  Or [Route("/Objectives", Required("CourseId")]
  or something similar like below etc. */
[Route("/Objectives")]
[MandatoryParam("CourseId")]
public Action List<Objectives> FilteredByCourse(int courseId){
    ...
}

[Route("/Objectives")]
[MandatoryParam("CategoryId")]
public Action List<Objectives> FilteredByCategory(int categoryId){
    ...
}
```

The desired outcome being that `/Objectives?courseId=5` and `/Objectives?categoryId=15` would route to two different actions.

I can't seem to find the correct search terms to use for this - they end up with articles talking about Model Binding or basic Routing, but nothing specific to this scenario. Does this not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that through `IActionConstraint` extensibility point . Create a custom `IActionConstraint` :

```
public class RequiredFromQueryActionConstraint : IActionConstraint
{
    private readonly string _parameter;

    public RequiredFromQueryActionConstraint(string parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    public int Order => 999;

    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
    {
        if (!context.RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey(_parameter))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Stitching it together via `IParameterModelConvention`:

```
public class RequiredFromQueryAttribute : FromQueryAttribute, IParameterModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ParameterModel parameter)
    {
        if (parameter.Action.Selectors != null && parameter.Action.Selectors.Any())
        {
            parameter.Action.Selectors.Last().ActionConstraints.Add(new RequiredFromQueryActionConstraint(parameter.BindingInfo?.BinderModelName ?? parameter.ParameterName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then apply to your route :

```
[Route("/Objectives")]
public IActionResult Action1([RequiredFromQueryAttribute] int courseId)
{
    return View();
}
[Route("/Objectives")]
public IActionResult Action2([RequiredFromQueryAttribute]int categoryId)
{
    return View();
}
```

Source code & article is from [here](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/09/required-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) .

The result : `http://localhost:xxxx/Objectives?courseId=1` will be redirected to `Action1` ;`http://localhost:xxxx/Objectives?categoryId=1` will be redirected to `Action2` ;`http://localhost:xxxx/Objectives` will get 404 error .